# How to update a Matplotlib plot while the program is running?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211) 
plt.axis([0,100, 95, 4000])  
plt.plot(array1,array2,'r')
plt.ylabel("label")
plt.xlabel("label")
plt.subplot(212)
plt.specgram(array3)
plt.show()
```

creates two nice diagrams. But how do you update its content without having to close the window?

I would need to create the window in one thread and, while a variable is being updated in the main code, the window is being updated using the variable.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options:
one is the great examples using mpl [examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/index.html). 
the second is writing the loops your self so you can understand what is going on. 
Here is a simple example using the pylab.draw() function instead of show(), it is not fancy, but it will allow you to understand the basic stuff:

```
import pylab
import time

pylab.ion() # animation on

# Note the comma after line. This is placed here because 
# plot returns a list of lines that are drawn.
line, = pylab.plot(0,1,'ro',markersize=6) 
pylab.axis([0,1,0,1])

line.set_xdata([1,2,3])  # update the data
line.set_ydata([1,2,3])
pylab.draw() # draw the points again
time.sleep(6)

line1, = pylab.plot([4],[5],'g*',markersize=8) 
pylab.draw() 

for i in range(10):
    line.set_xdata([1,2,3])  # update the data
    line.set_ydata([1,2,3])
    pylab.draw() # draw the points again
    time.sleep(1)

print "done up there"
line2, = pylab.plot(3,2,'b^',markersize=6)     
pylab.draw() 

time.sleep(20)
```

I hope this helps.